# What is the meaning of A += B == 1

Tags: c++, operators, conditional-operator

I have came across one type of usage of operator `=`. It was something like this:

```
A += B == 1;
```

where A and B are integers and this kind of usage I found in a function body.

I just kind of confused with the second `==` usage.

Of course I know the meaning of `A = B = 1;`

Can anybody explain me?

Comment: why the downvote? this is a clear question. please dont downvote if you just dont like the question, or think it is "too easy"

Comment: `A += (B == 1)`. Better?

Comment: Thanks for the answer: Now everything is clear and perfect. This way of coding makes code really nice and clean. Even-though sometimes, non-users would have some trouble in the beginning. Just like me.

Comment: @AndreasH. I didn't down-vote, but it might be due to the link to source code, which is a StackO no-no.

Comment: @JiveDadson: I see. I also did not like the link, but considered it as minor issue because the question is understandable without it. But yes, ideally, it should not be there.

Comment: Please never post ephemeral content like paste.ofcode.org on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code:

```
 A += B == 1;
```

is logically equal to:

```
bool b = B == 1;
A += b;
```

Note: `bool` can be implicitly converted to `int` (`true` to 1 and `false` to 0)

Comment: Okay.  I have got the idea for true and false cases. Then what is we get an another value after `==`, for example: line no. 19 in the mentioned source code. It was: `ans -= cnt[t[i]] == 2;` How should I read here?

Comment: Okay now I have got the idea from Pac0 's answer clearly.

Answer (score 1):

`==` has higher precedence over `+=`, so it's executed first

`B == 1` is a boolean expression, can be false or true

let's call that bool 'result'.

`A += result` is an addition + assignment (like `A = A + result` as you may already know).

Since A is an `int` in your case, the boolean `result` is implicitly converted to the number 1 if true, or 0 if false. (it would work similarily for other number types as well)

More on implicit conversions here : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion

So, at the end, this is logically equivalent to "increment A if and only if B is equal to 1" :

```
if (B == 1)
  A += 1;
```